# Dynamic arrays with C++

Tags: c++, arrays

my question refers to dynamic arrays in C++. I'm new at the language so please spell things out for me where possible.

I was wondering how I could change the following code to accept floats?

```
   #include <iostream> // include library

using namespace std;

   int main() // main function
      {
int length;
        cout << "Please enter the length of the array: "; // ask user for array
        cin >> length;

        int *dArray;
        dArray = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            dArray[i] = i;
        }

        for (   int i = 0;  i < length; i++)

        {
            cout << dArray[i] << " ";
        }
        delete[] dArray;
  return 0;
```

Comment: replace int with float where appropriate

Comment: Where are the appropriate areas? Can I define the array under a float instead of an int?

Comment: Replace the declaration and assignment of `dArray` with `float* dArray = new float [length];`.

Comment: Thank you vm molbdnilo, my code now fully executes!

Comment: you should use `std::vector<int>` , `std::vector<double>`, respectively. Do not use `int*` with `new` and `delete` unless you have good reasons to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more safe and easy way to write that code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   // std::vector
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length;
    cout << "Please enter the length of the array: ";
    cin >> length;

    vector<int> dArray( length );

    for( int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    {
        dArray[i] = i;
    }

    for( int i = 0;  i < length; ++i )
    {
        cout << dArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

The basic floating point type in C++ is called **`double`**. E.g. the literal `3.14` is of type `double`. So you can use that instead of `int` for the array item type.